# how to verify if any one expect is true out of multiple expect conditions

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, protractor

I have a Scenario where I search a text string and it could be part of any of the fields in the returned results, it could be in the title, or Summary or Description of the multiple results returned. I want to write a test which can match these 3 fields and if any one of these is true, then my test should pass.

How can I put multiple expect conditions with OR condition.

Comment: Check also my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800341/assert-an-array-reduces-to-true/37808169#37808169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with `protractor.promise.all()`:

```
var title = element(by.id("title")),
    summary = element(by.id("summary")),
    description = element(by.id("description"));

protractor.promise.all([
    title.isPresent(),
    summary.isPresent(),
    description.isPresent()
]).then(function (arrExists) {
    expect(arrExists.reduce(function(a,b) { return a || b; })).toBe(true);
});
```

This test would pass if *at least one of the 3 fields is present*.

---

If you are asking specifically about *waiting* for one of the elements to appear, you can use the [`protractor.ExpectedConditions.or()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.or):

```
var title = element(by.id("title")),
    summary = element(by.id("summary")),
    description = element(by.id("description"));

browser.wait(EC.or(
    EC.presenceOf(title), 
    EC.presenceOf(summary),
    EC.presenceOf(description)), 5000);
```

Comment: I do not want to check presence of the element, I want to check that the searched text is matching with the returned results and search text could be in any of these 3 fields(title,summary, description) of the result. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, we can use OR as like below

```
      String expected="cool"; //this is my expected value

      String actual1="cool"; //get title from driver
      String actual2="xyz"; //get summary from driver
      String actual3="abc"; //get required text from driver

    Assert.assertTrue((expected.equals(actual1)) | (expected.equals(actual2)) | (expected.equals(actual3)));
```

If you are looking for checking particular word in sentence of title or summary, below way will be helpful.

```
      String actual1="its very cool"; //get title from driver
      String actual2="xyz"; //get summary from driver
      String actual3="abcd"; //get required text from driver

    //here i am checking for cool      
    Assert.assertTrue((actual1.matches(".*cool.*")) | (actual2.matches(".*cool.*")) | (actual3.matches(".*cool.*")));
```

Comment: Thansk for your reply @murali  but I am looking for the resolution in Protractor.