# Assert an array reduces to true

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, jasmine, protractor

In one of the tests, we need to assert that one of the 3 elements is present. Currently we are doing it using the `protractor.promise.all()` and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var title = element(by.id("title")),
    summary = element(by.id("summary")),
    description = element(by.id("description"));

protractor.promise.all([
    title.isPresent(),
    summary.isPresent(),
    description.isPresent()
]).then(function (arrExists) {
    expect(arrExists.reduce(function(a,b) { return a || b; })).toBe(true);
});
```

Is there a *better way* to solve it with *Jasmine* without resolving the promises explicitly? Would we need a custom matcher or it is possible to solve with the built-in matchers?

Comment: Note that instead of `reduce` you could use `arrExists.some(function (a) {return a;})`. With Jasmine you would use the [`done` argument in the `it` callback](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support), and call it when you are done with the test. I don't think there is a better way. You need anyway to wait for the promises to resolve.

Comment: @trincot thanks for the point. I should've probably mentioned that [`expect()` is "patched" in Protractor to implicitly resolve promises](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#protractor-adaptations)..but since I have to combine the results of multiple promises with each other, it might not help in this case.

Comment: You should supply `false` as the initial value so that it works on empty arrays as well. Or just use `.some(Boolean)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

let title = EC.visibilityOf($("#title")),
    summary = EC.visibilityOf($("#summary")),
    description = EC.visibilityOf($("#description"));

expect(EC.or(title, summary, description)() ).toBeTruthy('Title or summary or description should be visible on the page')
```

Notice that i am executing function that ExpectedCondition returns - so i am getting result of that function(Promise that will be resolved to boolean) instead of function.

You can use .presenceOf() if you need it instead .visibilityOf()

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.or

Comment: Awesome idea to use Expected Conditions, never thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply get all the elements with a single selector and assert that the count is superior to zero:

```
var title_summary_description = element.all(by.css("#title, #summary, #description"));
expect(title_summary_description.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```